# Apache and mod_wsgi, worker process stuck to W state, request never dies. How to diagnose?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi, mpm-worker

I am running Apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi, Python 2.7 and mpm_worker. Occassionally, one of the worker *processes* gets stuck and all of it threads stop in writing state (as demostrated in the screenshot below).

This happens ~once in a day for one worker process.

I assume this is either because

- Some internal problem in Apache
- All of my Python threads inside the mod_wsgi worker process deadlock somehow

Thus far, the only remedy I have found is Apache full restart (not graceful).

I'd hope to find some pointers how to diagnose the issue what is causing it

- Why Apace `Timeout` does not kill the worker threads / processes. Time `timeout` is one minute, but looks like those threads and workers have been running happily several hours on one request.
- Is it possible to obtain thread dump from inside `mod_wsgi`and see if the Python thread themselves are somehow deadlocked
- Any idea what could be causing this and how to remedy the situation?

Below is an screenshot showing Apache `server-status` where one of the worker processes (1-0) is stuck.

[image]

Comment: Might be duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/496491/apache-mpm-worker-wsgi-python-django-workers-stuck

Comment: Are you using WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}. There are various Python modules that will not work in sub processes and if they deadlock, will bring the process down. Anyway, you should hop on the mod_wsgi mailing list and monitor it, have some new monitoring tools that can help monitor issues like this that have been talking about recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After turning on `WSGIDaemonProcess` and switching to separate daemon processes this issue has not appeared anymore, as recommended in the linked question.